# Is 'price hike' synonymous with 'price rise'?

Tags: definition, nonexpert, price

Since my childhood I have a belief that in *economics* **price rise** and **price hike** synonymous with each other.

Moreover, the Collin dictionary strengthens by belief:

[Hike](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/price-hike)

But what you experts have to say--- are they absolutely same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are used interchangeably in the literature e.g. see the occurrences printed in Mankiw Principles of Economics. For example, on page 509 its used completely interchangeably:

> If a Pennsylvania gun manufacturer **raises the price**
> of rifles it sells to the U.S. Army, **its price hikes will
> increase**...

Price hike is also not special economic jargon, it is used pretty much consistently with dictionary definition.

> A hike is a sudden or large increase in prices...